# Undo name hiding by "using" keyword. Does not work in grandchild class

Tags: c++, name-hiding

For example in below program I undo name hiding by "using" keyword. If I have base and one derived class "im getting expected ambiguous call error". But if I have two derived class(child and grand child) now child and grand child having same overloaded function here also I undo name hiding by "using" keyword. But It is getting compiled and got output. My question is why im not getting error as "ambiguous call to overloaded function".

```
class baseNameHiding
{
protected:
int nameHidingexample(int t)
{
    cout<<"im baseeeeeeeeeeee"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
};
class derivedNameHiding:public baseNameHiding
{   
public:
    float nameHidingexample(float s)
    {
        cout<<"im derived"<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
    using baseNameHiding::nameHidingexample;

};
class grandDerivedNameHiding:public derivedNameHiding
{
public:
    float nameHidingexample(float f)
    {
        cout<<"im grand derived"<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
    using baseNameHiding::nameHidingexample;
    using derivedNameHiding::nameHidingexample;

};
int main()
{
    char a;float f = 0.0;
    derivedNameHiding derived;
    derived.nameHidingexample(0);
    grandDerivedNameHiding grandchild;
    grandchild.nameHidingexample(f);
    cin>>a;
} 


//output
im baseeeeeeeeeeee
im grand derived
```

Comment: The key is `nameHidingexample(0)` vs `nameHidingexample(f)`: the first `0` is an `int`, while the second one is a `float`. If I turn the first `0` into `f`, I get a consistent behavior (output: derived/grand derived). My guess is that promotion is applied at an unexpected time, but I'm not an expert on C++ argument dependent lookup to know the details. (And honestly the code tries quite hard to involve some corner case of the spec in a confusing/lawyer-ish way.)

Answer (score 3):

You have encountered a special rule of *using-declarations*. C++14 [namespace.udecl]/15:

> When a *using-declaration* brings names from a base class into a
>   derived class scope, member functions and member function templates in
>   the derived class override and/or hide member functions and member
>   function templates with the same name, *parameter-type-list*,
>   *cv-qualification*, and *ref-qualifier* (if any) in a base class (rather than conflicting). [...]
>   [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> struct B {
>     virtual void f(int);
>     virtual void f(char);
>     void g(int);
>     void h(int);
> };
>
> struct D : B {
>     using B::f;
>     void f(int);    // OK: D::f(int) overrides B::f(int);
>
>     using B::g;
>     void g(char);   // OK
>
>     using B::h;
>     void h(int);    // OK: D::h(int) hides B::h(int)
> };
>
> void k(D* p)
> {
>     p->f(1);        // calls D::f(int)
>     p->f(’a’);      // calls B::f(char)
>     p->g(1);        // calls B::g(int)
>     p->g(’a’);      // calls D::g(char)
> }
> ```
>
> — *end example* ]

Comment: The `;` in the comment *OK: D::f(int) overrides B::f(int);* is in fact in the C++14 IS.